# SharpZipLib - zero bytes

Tags: c#, .net, io, sharpziplib

I am trying to implement [SharpZipLib](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples#anchorMemory)

So I copied the below snippet from their samples:

```
// Compresses the supplied memory stream, naming it as zipEntryName, into a zip,
// which is returned as a memory stream or a byte array.
//
public MemoryStream CreateToMemoryStream(MemoryStream memStreamIn, string zipEntryName) 
{
    MemoryStream outputMemStream = new MemoryStream();
    ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputMemStream);

    zipStream.SetLevel(3); //0-9, 9 being the highest level of compression

    ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(zipEntryName);
    newEntry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

    zipStream.PutNextEntry(newEntry);

    StreamUtils.Copy(memStreamIn, zipStream, new byte[4096]);
    zipStream.CloseEntry();

    zipStream.IsStreamOwner = false;    // False stops the Close also Closing the underlying stream.
    zipStream.Close();          // Must finish the ZipOutputStream before using outputMemStream.

    outputMemStream.Position = 0;
    return outputMemStream;

    // Alternative outputs:
    // ToArray is the cleaner and easiest to use correctly with the penalty of duplicating allocated memory.
    byte[] byteArrayOut = outputMemStream.ToArray();

    // GetBuffer returns a raw buffer raw and so you need to account for the true length yourself.
    byte[] byteArrayOut = outputMemStream.GetBuffer();
    long len = outputMemStream.Length;
}
```

I copy pasted that function and called it this way:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"c:\file.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
    file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
    ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
    var result = SharpZip.CreateToMemoryStream(ms, "file.jpg");
    result.WriteTo(new FileStream(@"c:\myzip.zip", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write));
}
```

The **myzip.zip** is sucessfully created, but the file.jpg inside has zero bytes.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: have you stepped thru the code what is the value of result when you are writing to / creating the new FileStream..?

Comment: yes, its a valid memory stream. The **myzip.zip** is created, the **file.jpg** is also created inside, but the image has zero bytes.

Comment: Doesn't closing the zipstream close the underlying memory stream? Which would explain why you have no data.

Comment: look at the accepted answer here in this posing I would change the code to use a while loop as well as Buffer Chunks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597295/how-do-i-use-file-readallbytes-in-chunks

Comment: @Sign Not sure about that, but if that's the case, how can I save it? ``zipStream.Close();          // Must finish the ZipOutputStream before using outputMemStream.``

Comment: read your stream in chunks using a while loop that's how

Comment: Not sure why do you say that. I have my filestream filled when I call ``SharpZip.CreateToMemoryStream(ms, "file.jpg");``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to "rewind" the input `MemoryStream` after writing the input file data:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(@"input file path"))
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[file.Length];
    file.Read(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
    ms.Write(bytes, 0, (int)file.Length);
    ms.Position = 0; // "Rewind" the stream to the beginning.
    var result = SharpZip.CreateToMemoryStream(ms, "file.jpg");
    using (var outputStream = File.Create(@"output file path"))
    {
        result.WriteTo(outputStream);
    }
}
```

Alternative (slightly simplified) version of the implementation:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"input file path");
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    var result = SharpZip.CreateToMemoryStream(ms, "file.jpg");
    using (var outputStream = File.Create(@"output file path"))
    {
        result.WriteTo(outputStream);
    }
}
```