# Parsing thousands of files causes slowdown

Tags: c#, xml, file, system.io.file

I am trying to parse roughly 300k XML files in just under 400 folders.

Each file is small and for the first 80 to 130 folders achieve an average of 0 miliseconds per file. After a variable number of files processed however, this shows down to an average of 6 miliseconds per file.

The slowdown does not kick in at the same point on any given run.

I've tried adding a `Thread.Sleep(5000)` and `GC.Collect()` in the program if the average time is greater than a milisecond (to no effect).

In watching the CPU, memory and, disk usage, they don't seem to get out of hand at all.

Here's a sample of the code which I've been running on my local machine. I don't think there's anything controversial in here, unless there's something odd within XMLDocument.Load

```
    public void Traversefolders()
    {
        string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(debug_root + @"\App_Data\AllPublicXML");
        Console.WriteLine($"Searching for data in {folders.Count()} folders");
        int total = folders.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            ReadFiles(i, total, folders[i]);
        }
    }

    public void ReadFiles(int index, int total, string folder)
    {
        Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
        s.Start();

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles($@"{folder}", "*.xml");

        foreach (string file in files) {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(file);
            // READ XML DOC
            // at this point I am checking the value of a single 
            // field in the XML doc
            // eventually more will happen here, but I’m in early 
            // dev phases
            // and am prototyping
        }
        double avg = s.ElapsedMilliseconds / files.Count();
        Console.WriteLine($"Completed {Path.GetFileName(folder)} including {files.Length} files in {s.ElapsedMilliseconds} miliseconds (avg: {avg}) {index+1} of {total}");

        if (avg > 1) {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            GC.Collect();
        }

    }
```

Does anyone have experience with slowdowns while parsing through large amounts of files in C#?

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: are you possibly encountering anti virus software?

Comment: what's going on in `// READ XML DOC`?  It might be important.

Comment: Could be your program, could be something outside your .NET runtime environment like OS file caching, 3rd party-services interfering with/intercepting storage I/O accesses, or simply some effect of the storage hardware/system you use. In short, it could be basically (almost) anything. Right now, with the very limited amount of information in the question, all we can do here is playing a game of pinning the tail on the donkey...

Comment: If you touch lots of files in short time, several anti-virus have heuristics to avoid ransom-ware ... guess what they do : touch lots of files in a short time. Essentially that 5-10times the time needed for f.e. copying those files because now each is watched for "encryption" happening (take file, read id, copy it encrypted, delete original)

Comment: `XmlDocument` has a pretty heavy memory footprint.  You might simply be spending time in garbage collection.  Have you profiled?  Could you try replacing your current algorithm with a streaming algorithm, and measure the performance difference?  If streaming is much faster than `XmlDocument` then it's probably something in your code.  If performance is similarly bad then it might be something with the OS like antivirus software.

Comment: Are the files being indexed? So after you open so quickly the Operating System indexes?

Comment: @elgonzo - `File.ReadAllBytes()` can return a byte array large enough to go on the large object heap.  `XmlDocument.Load()` is less likely to do that.  Reading in chunks would work great though, see [How do I use File.ReadAllBytes In chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11597295).

Comment: @dbc, true, didn't think about that...

Comment: Side note: `$@"{folder}"` is exactly the same as `folder`, because the `@` has only an effect on string literals (string constants), but not on the content of variables. I.e., `@` is only effective at compile time. It doesn't do anything at runtime.

Comment: Once I measured - `Xdocument` quite faster than `XmlDocument`

Comment: Have you tried using VS Profiling to figure exactly what statements are slower?

Comment: I doubt this is a .net problem or anything you can fix with code. It sounds environmental.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion so far, I will test the same code on a different computer without antivirus installed

Comment: Are you tracking memory usage? Does it progressively increase?

Comment: Remove code in if statement.  The garbage collecting is probably slowing things down and why wait 5 seconds.

Comment: @jdweng that was in order to figure out if there was a memory leak issue of some sort, or if there were resources not being released somewhere. As of now I suspect the most likely candidate is antivirus software protecting against excessive file access, but I've still got to test that theory (which means downloading a large dataset to another machine ... which is in progress now)